How to use threads in for loop
I have a method call in a while loop with different objects but it was taking time as it will wait for method execution to complete on each loop iteration.
Is there any way that I can call the methods in parallel without waiting for method completion?
Sample code below:
while (iter.hasNext) {
    Object value = iter.next();
    result.add(method(value));
}

Is there any way to call method(value) in parallel for several values?

Without more context we can't help you much. But if possible, you may use a parallel Stream. More: how would you like to aggregate all the values ?

In simple way method(value) was exciting one by one with different values it was taking time to complete execution as it was happening one by one. I am trying to execute method(value) parallellly to reduce the time

Sure but if parallelised what will you do with all the values coming in random order?

Not enough info. What is result? Is add method thread-safe? Is this operation CPU-bound, or does it involve blocking such as logging, file I/O, network calls, database access, etc.? How many tasks to be run in the background?

Before posting here, search Stack Overflow thoroughly. Multi-threading and concurrency has been covered many many times already.

I can suggest you to use Thread Pool:
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
List<String> values = List.of("value1", "value2");
for (Object value : values) {
  executorService.submit(() -> {
      System.out.println(value);
  });
}

With this setup, the elements of the list are processed in parallel

Basically you have 2 options, depends if you need to process every case,
or whether you are looking for any (fastest, possible or positive) one.
In a nutshell, you could use queue of workers (threads), maybe like this:
// Concurrent queue for workers
ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Integer> queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();       

// Build the queue of defined interval - either for every case, or group them by some criteria (by 10, 100, ...)


// Create Callable workers (while building the queue)
  List<Callable<int[]>> workers = new ArrayList<>();
  for( int i = 1; i < THREADS; i++ )
    workers.add( getAtomicResults );

// sizing parallelism might be important - CPU cores, -1 for kernel
THREADS = Math.max(1, -1 + Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());

// Let workers do their jobs, collect the results - either find the solution or add another one ...
  List<Future<int[]>> results;
  ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newWorkStealingPool( THREADS - 1 );
  try {
    results = executorService.invokeAll( workers );
    
  } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { return failedExecutor( e.getMessage() ); }

// collect the data, terminate or continue ...    
  for ( Future<int[]> future : results ) {
    if ( future.isCancelled() )
      return failedWorker( future.toString() );
    
    try {
      int[] result = future.get();
      ...
    }
}


// Your atomic implementation ...
Callable<int[]> getAtomicResults = () -> {
}


You may simply use pool threading and futures...
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10); // Thread pool
List<Future<RETURNTYPEOFMETHOD>> results = new ArrayList<>(); // Collector of results
for (TYPEOFVALUE value : values) {
   results.add(() -> { return method(value); }); // push the job to the pool
}
for (var r : results) { // wait for results one by one in the exact order of job submission
    var result = r.get(); // get a result
    // do what you want with a result
}

If you need to collect result as soon as they are produced:
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10); // Thread pool
BlockingQueue<RETURNTYPEOFMETHOD> results = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(); // Collector of results
for (TYPEOFVALUE value : values) {
   executor.submit(() -> { results.add(method(value) } ); // push the job to the pool
}

for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) { // get all results
    var result = results.take(); // get a result as soon as one is provided
    // do what you want with a result
}

With a stream given the iterator:
List<RETURNTYPEOFMETHOD> results = StreamSupport.stream(iter.spliterator(),true) // parallel stream
    .map(v -> method(v))
    .collect(Collectors.toList())

